# NVMe doesn't boot anymore after swap

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, bios

I had an NVMe drive from a dead laptop that I needed to recover data from. I don't have any sort of adapter so I removed the NVMe from my working Linux tower and swapped in the target for recovery.

I recovered the data using a live CD, no problem. I did accidentally boot into the Windows OS once on the recovery NVMe by accident. I was surprised it even worked.

When I swapped back in my Linux Ubuntu NVMe, guess what? Doesn't boot anymore. I never changed any BIOS setting or data on the drive. It shows up in the boot menus but says "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key"

Since then I've tried fiddling with all the boot BIOS settings, reinstalling Grub in the drive, clearing CMOS, rewriting the partition table. The drive appears perfectly normal when mounted to a live CD.

The drive has Ubuntu installed on it and boots using EFI. The motherboard is an ASRock steel legend.

What the heck did I break and how? Is there any way to boot again?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the boot partition of the original drive was damaged during removal or reinsertion.

1. Booting from a live USB, e.g, [Ubuntu Live](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started), make a complete image of the drive as it is now. **Verify it**.
2. Restore BIOS/UEFI setting to the state they were in *before* performing data recovery.
3. If you *have* a *previous* disk image, restore that image, and see if the PC now boots correctly.
4. If you do *not* have an image, remove all partitions, boot from Live Ubuntu, and install Ubuntu *de novo*.
5. In either case, recover data from the image made in step 1. It might be possible to restore the entire Linux partition at once.

Answer (score -1):

The NVMe drive probably isn't in the boot sequence in the UEFI set up. You also might want to use `gdisk` to restore the partition table from the backup, which is stored on every drive with gpt partitioning.

But first make sure the boot drive is in the boot sequence. You can also look at how your PCIe slots are configured. Make sure the drive slot is active. Clean the contacts on the drive.

In UEFI set up, make sure compatibility mode is set up, and `operating system` is set to `other os` or something similar.

Make sure `secure boot` is not active. But I really think the boot drive is not in the boot sequence. On boot up, you hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to get a drive menu. See if  the NVMe drive is listed. If it is, select it, and try to boot.